Time series model and stationarity
Consider the very simple model predicting $y_t$ as function on $x_t$, built with real-data, given by:
$y_t = a + b.x_t$
For such system, we need both $y_t$ and $x_t$ to be I(0), but here I am talking about a practical application with real, noisy data. In my case $y_t$ is definitely stationarity using ADF, PP and KPSS tests. The issue is that $x_t$ "looks" stationary and is "intuitively" stationarity but it fails 2 out of 3 stationarity tests based on the time range used to build my model.
If I extend the range to assess stationarity, then $x_t$ passes 2 or 3 tests implying that on the long-term $x_t$ is stationary. Note that if I push the range from 1980 to 2024, it becomes non-stationary again.
Questions:

Is the argument of extending the range to assess stationary valid to support the use $x_t$?

Any literature on this topic?

If stationarity can be assessed on a different range than the one used to build a model valid, how do I reconcile this with the fact that the regression coefficients do not change while arguing that $x_t$ is stationary on a longer term or even that $x_t$ is "intuitively" stationary. Therefore how a model can become Mathematically sounds by arguing it is?



Could you explain why the series $(x_t)$ must look stationary?  Nothing in the formula implies that, and there would be nothing mathematically unsound about such a model with a nonstationary $(x_t),$ so there must be additional information you're using to draw that conclusion.
